# Devexpress XtraChart sorts series by default

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress

I've a Devexpress XtraChart (Bar Chart) that displays gender information over range of months and years. Here is how I set some of the properties:

```
DataTable chartTable = new DataTable("Table1");

chartTable.Columns.Add("Gender");
chartTable.Columns.Add("MonthYear");

chartTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));

foreach (var p in chart.getChartData())
{
    chartTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { p.Gender, p.MonthYear, p.Value });
}

// chartByGender is the name of the XtraChart control   
chartByGender.DataSource = chartTable;
chartByGender.SeriesDataMember = "gender";
chartByGender.SeriesTemplate.ArgumentDataMember = "MonthYear";
chartByGender.SeriesTemplate.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "value" });

chartByGender.SeriesSorting = SortingMode.None;
chartByGender.SeriesTemplate.SeriesPointsSorting = SortingMode.None;
```

However, when the chart is displayed it doesn't display the data in the order it is available in `chartTable`. It rather sorts them and I really don't want it to do so. What properties should I change so that the series could be the same as what is in `chartTable`'s order?

Is there any way to force the control not to sort the data elements?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this DevExpress Chart demo:
[Link](http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/DataBinding/SeriesBinding.aspx)

It has a few sort options for the chart, maybe it can help you solve the problem.